# Convert $ to Local Currency in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, currency, nsnumberformatter, nslocale

I've read questions about formatting a currency but nothing seems to provide me an answer with my question.
I tried the code suggestions I found but all i get were the same values with different currency symbols.
For example:
$1 -> ₩1

What I want to know is a way to actually convert the amount to its local currency's equivalent.
For example:
$1 -> ₩1011.75

Is there a possible way to do this using Apple's API?

I have a table that displays a list of the products I offer. They are all in USD. I want it to be displayed properly depending on the region.
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Doesn't the exchange rate constantly change?  Have you considered the implications of that?

Comment: Yah. that's why Milo introduced possible external services to use. I was hoping Apple already has an integrated api for this (including fetching the updated data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this library to help you out. If you have any issues, then just leave a comment below. [MGCurrencyExchanger](https://github.com/GenralDesigns/MGCurrencyExchanger)

Comment: @user1681701 I updated it a tiny bit, see the end of the read me file.

Answer (score 0):

NSNumberFormatter will give you currency styling. 
But Apple doesn't provide exchange rates APIs. 
For that you'll need to use a 3rd party web service like Yahoo!

Comment: do you know any 3rd party web service I can use?

Comment: Yahoo Has one. That's what Apple's calculator app on OSX uses.

Comment: @user1681701 Try this: https://openexchangerates.org/ It's perfect, and has a JSON call and everything.

Comment: @Milo Thank you for the quick reply. This means that internet connection is required. So, for users who aren't connected, they will still see the non converted version. :( Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: The thing to do is store the value when you are able to check. And also note the date it was updated. Real time currency rates are quite expensive. But it would always require a network connection. Currency rates change constantly.